# Keynote 6.0 - How to add animated gif?

Tags: macos, keynote, quicktime

I recently got Keynote 6.0 and I'm having trouble animating a gif in it. Using Insert > Choose... easily adds the gif to the slide, but without animation. I have searched and found other sources ([example](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4446062?start=0&tstart=0)) which all seem to point to using the "Quicktime Inspector" to work with the animation of a gif. Unfortunately, the Quicktime Inspector no longer seems to exist in version 6.0 and I can't seem to find the solution otherwise. Any suggestions? Thank you much!

Comment: Keynote 6.2 added support for animated GIFs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change the extension to `.mov` then drag it over, it’ll ask you to optimize for iOS, at which point it will treat the GIF as a movie.

Comment: This works only if you have the .mov file (and not just by changing the animated gif extension)

Comment: @AlexPopescu Seems to work for me. Just tried using a simple `mv lol.gif lol.mov` and then dragging the file to Keynote 6.

Comment: This worked for me twice in a row just now, and I was happy, and then 4 other .gifs did not work. Keynote gives an error: "Media could not be inserted." Apparently it only works for certain types of GIFs but I have no idea what the qualifications are.

Comment: Does *NOT* work in Keynote 6.5.3, tried with two different GIFs. Keynote gives the error, The operation could not be completed`

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, animated GIFs (and Flash animations) are no longer supported in Keynote. You would probably have to use `ffmpeg` or QTPro to convert the GIFs to movie files and re-import them.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was fixed in Keynote v6.2. Update Keynote and it should work. (as mislav informed me in the comments)

Comment: You can't add animated GIF's to the iCloud version of Keynote though....This only works on the native desktop app. Unless someone can prove me wrong...

Comment: Not sure why this was up-voted; does **not** work in Keynote 6.5.3

Comment: @jm3: Probably because the answer clearly states "v6.2", and it worked then. Even if it doesn't work in "v6.5".

Answer (score 0):

They won't animate until you view the slideshow, but should there. Also, go to the Inspector>Quicktime Tab and make sure to change the Repeat setting from None to Looping.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I did mention in the question that in the new version of Keynote, the Quicktime Inspector doesn't seem to exist any longer. Also, it doesn't seem that the GIF is animated even in the slideshow (in the new version of keynote).

Answer (score 0):

The new Keynote (v6) doesn't import GIFs in like it used to, which is disappointing.

However, if you open an old Keynote presentation (Keynote '09), Keynote v6 will ask you if you want to update and/or optimize it for iOS devices.  If you optimize, it will render the animated GIF into .m4v.  Once that is done, if the Format inspection, you will have a "Movie" tab.

The down side is that you MUST have Keynote '09.  I tried to export an animated GIF created in Keynote v6 as Keynote '09.  It did not maintain the animated GIF correctly, so when I reopened it, I did not get the "Optimize" option

Answer (score 0):

if you want a GIF to repeat itself, as beroe correctly pointed out, save the .gif to some folder, change it's file extension (make sure to show the real extension and not hide it (cmd+'i' is the canonical version, change it there if you're unsure)) to .mov and then drag it to keynote 6. Optimize for iOS and now select "endless" in the "format->Film" section under "repeat" (I don't know the correct translations as I use a german keynote).

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to import an animated gif into Keynote 6.2.2, so I converted it to mp4 via https://cloudconvert.com/anything-to-mp4  (I googled "convert animated gif to mp4"), and then I was able to just drag and drop the mp4 into Keynote.